# How to go through all rows in employeeID column in database and retrieve hourly pay rate one at a time?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have the following sql table called employee_info with two important columns, "employeeID" and "HourlyRate". What I want to do is get the HourlyRate from each employeeID one at a time, do calculations on that and then store it in another database with the same primary key employeeID, and then repeat the whole process for the next employeeID and so on until all are completed.

[image]

So far  I have tried this very basic incomplete code to try and retrieve the information, but I am unsure how to do the above, help is appreciated, thanks

```
        boolean st = false;
        PreparedStatement ps3 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT HourlyRate FROM payroll_system.employee_info");
        ResultSet rs = ps3.executeQuery(); 
        st = rs.next();
        float hourlyRate = rs.getFloat("HourlyRate");
```

Test logic:

```
                PreparedStatement ps3 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT HourlyRate FROM payroll_system.employee_info");
            ResultSet rs = ps3.executeQuery(); 
            while(rs.next()) {
                float hourlyRate = rs.getFloat("HourlyRate");
                String employee_id = rs.getString("employeeID"); 

                PreparedStatement ps4 = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE payroll_system.payslip SET basic = ? WHERE employeeID=?"); 
                ps4.setFloat(1, hourlyRate);
                ps4.setString(2, employee_id);
                ps4.executeUpdate(); 




            }
```

Comment: You making Select without employeeID and next you are making getString("employeeID") so you have got null everytime. Try to change
SELECT employeeID, HourlyRate FROM payroll_system.employee_info where employeeID=1234

Comment: Oops, that 1234 was a mistake, just used that for testing.

Comment: @Thodgnir Hi again! I updated the test logic again, and it's still not working, could you please check again? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate trough the result-set.
See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html

```
rs.first();
while( rs.next() ){
    float hourlyRate = rs.getFloat("HourlyRate");
    int employeeID   = rs.getInt("employeeID ");
    //Do your code to calculate and update other database....
    //You need to check for INSERT or UPDATE in the other database.
    //Make one select on the current tupel

    //e.g.
    PreparedStatement checkUpdateOrInsert = conOnOtherDb.prepareStatement("SELECT employeeID FROM otherSchema.otherTable");
    ResultSet rsCheckUpdateOrInsert = checkUpdateOrInsert .executeQuery();
    if( !rsCheckUpdateOrInsert.first() ){
        //On onther DB you must insert
    }//untested, (bool) first should return false on no row?
    else{
        //On onther DB you must update
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question the simple way to do this is to make something like this:

```
    PreparedStatement ps3 = con.prepareStatement("SELECT employeeID, HourlyRate FROM payroll_system.employee_info");
    ResultSet rs = ps3.executeQuery(); 
    Statement statement2 = con.createStatement(); // for update query        
    while(rs.next()){
        float hourlyRate = rs.getFloat("HourlyRate");
        int employeeID = rs.getInt("employeeID");
        //Do calculations
        String sql_update = "UPDATE...";
        statement2.executeUpdate(sql_update);
    }
```

It should do the trick.

Comment: Essentially what the previous answer suggested. Great to see that there is a common solution, thanks very much Thodgnir!

Comment: Yup i ended writing this code while @raiserle posted his answer, so i posted my to confirm :)

Comment: By the way, will an update statement work if there is a null value in the database? Or does it only work to replace an actual value?

Comment: this statement2.executeUpdate executing normal sql update like "UPDATE  payroll_system.employee_info SET FirstName = 'hank' WHERE employeeID = " + employeeID. So basicly there is no matter if there is null value or not.

Comment: Hmm I was just testing to see if your logic worked, but the database is not updating, could you please take a look at my test code in the updated question :)

Comment: actually it's still not working! Is there supposed to be a where clause in the initial preparedstatement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117940/discussion-between-thodgnir-and-javaprogrammer).

Comment: please check the updated question, at the bottom I used your suggested logic.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of calculations, do you have to do ? can it be done in sql it self ?
If so, 
you can 
either

```
CREATE TABLE payroll_system.cal_hourly_rates as 
SELECT employeeID, calculate(hourlyRate) calcRate 
FROM payroll_system.employee_info
```

if `payroll_system.cal_hourly_rates` is already created

```
INSERT INTO payroll_system.cal_hourly_rates cal(employeeID, calcRate) 
SELECT employeeID, calculate(hourlyRate) calcRate 
FROM payroll_system.employee_info einfo
WHERE einfo.employeeID != cal.employeeID
```

Comment: Hi Georgy! Thanks very much for your response, however I believe the other two answers will provide the most effective solution in this instance. The calculations basically require information retrieval from other tables such as tax information, hours worked by employee etc, then all that information is updated into a payslip table which contains columns for net_salary, gross_salary,superannuation, tax payable etc..

Comment: since all the data is in the database it self, you need not get the values back in Java client and round trip 
check if "calculate" function can do all the calculations you mentioned. It will be very slow otherwise